# How to change total items number in Draft and Awaiting Approval header in workbox

Tags: workbox

I have customized my workbox, showing filtered items and its works perfectly. However I am unable to change number of items showing in Draft and Awaiting Aproval header as highlighted with red box in below image

[image]

Do anybody know how to change this total items number in Draft and Awaiting Approval header in workbox?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more how you customized the workbox?
Eg. what kind of filtering you applied and where you did this

The Workbox is rendered by the WorkboxForm.cs in Sitecore.Client. The count is set in method DisplayStates.

If you haven't done already, you can always add the complete WorkboxForm.cs to your project and update the CodeBeside reference in the /sitecore/shell/Applications/Workbox/Workbox.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

The place you are looking for is in the `Sitecore.Client.dll` as pointed out by Koen Heye.

The class `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm` contains a method called **DisplayStates** which formats the state **DisplayName** and count of items in the workflow with that state.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is post is a couple years old already but in case there are others looking, these are the steps I took to achieve this:

1. Find the Workbox.xml file \sitecore\shell\Applications\Workbox\Workbox.xml located in the IIS folder
2. Copy it to \sitecore\shell\override
3. Change the `CodeBeside` node to point to a custom `Class, Namespace`
4. Create a your class that inherits from `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm`
5. Override the `DisplayState()` method like so:

   ```
   protected override void DisplayState(IWorkflow workflow, WorkflowState state, StateItems stateItems, Control control, int offset, int pageSize)
   {
       // call the base class method
       base.DisplayState(workflow, state, regionalStateItems, control, offset, pageSize);
       // get the control containing the header with the number of items
       Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Section xmlControl = control.Parent as 
       Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Section;
       // set the header to whatever text you want
       xmlControl.Header = "Anything you want";
   }
   ```

Comment: Its good to know that we have "xmlControl.Header" as an option.